# Como fazer uma coluna ocupar o restante do espaço disponível?

Tags: css, css3

Gostaria de por dois blocos dentro de uma div de tamanho paralelo, um com tamanho fixo, e outro que coubesse exatamente no espaço restante.

Por exemplo :

```
div#container {
  width: 50%; /* este tamanho se altera */
  height: 100px;
}

#esquerdo {
  width: 100%
  height: 100px;
}
#direito {
  width: 40px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

quero os blocos **#esquerdo** e **#direito** lado a lado preenchendo o container.
veja aqui : http://jsfiddle.net/nmqhyuz3/

O que devo fazer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso com Flexbox:

1. Faça com que o `#container` possua leiaute flex:

   ```
   div#container {
       display: flex;
   ```
2. O elemento da esquerda, cujo tamanho deve ocupar o máximo do espaço disponível, você estabelece que ele cresce livremente:

   ```
   #esquerdo {
       /*width: 100%*/
       flex-grow: 1;
   ```
3. O da direita fica inalterado - o valor padrão para `flex-grow` é zero, de modo que ele não vai crescer além da largura determinada.

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmqhyuz3/1/).

Comment: Esse "leiaute" me matou...

Comment: @JorgeB Tem gente que acha feio (**muita** gente), mas eu gosto, e pelo menos em pt_BR é correto. *layout* também é correto, é claro, e "mata" bem menos gente... :P

Comment: Eu sei que é correto em pt_BR. Mas acho um crime  alguém se lembrar de criar a palavra em português com a sonoridade do inglês. Mas valia fazer com todas assim ao menos sabiam falar todos inglês :P

Comment: eu estava boiando sem entender a palavra "leiaute" até o comentário do @Jorge B.. rsrsrsr

Comment: @JorgeB. E se eu te contar que alguns políticos brasileiros queriam que mudássemos a grafia de "pizza" para "píteça"? Triste, mas verdadeiro. Ainda bem que não emplacou.

Comment: @bfavaretto isso é sotaque. Aqui se mudassemos consoante o sotaque estavamos perdidos. Aqui dizemos "pidza"

Comment: Quem aprende *layout* antes de *leiaute* realmente tem uma certa dificuldade. O mesmo ocorre com *container* e *contêiner*, e tantas outras (já vi até "mause"). Não existe certo... mas sim o apropriado. Na minha opinião qualquer uma dessas palavras é apropriada no SOPT.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo eu não acho bem aportuguesar o inglês. Qualquer dia só se fala "Ai lâve iu" em vem de "eu te amo"

Comment: Bem, o display: flex; do #container não permite que eu adicione outro bloco dentro do container, que quebre, os blocos ficam sempre lado a lado, não importa o que eu faça! tem jeito ??? Obrigado!!!

Comment: @DanilloEder Adicione `flex-wrap: wrap;` no seu container, e crie novas `div`s nos pontos em que você quer que uma quebra ocorra; essas `div`s só precisam ter `flex-basis: 100%`, e mais nada. [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/nmqhyuz3/2/).

Comment: Cara, tu é massa demais mano! Muito obrigado! Que Deus te abençoe !!! vlw

Answer (score 5):

É possível fazer isso com `float`, bastando alterar a ordem dos elementos no HTML... o `direito` deverá vir primeiro e o `esquerdo` depois:

```css
/* ESTILOS IMPORTANTES PARA A RESPOSTA */
#esquerdo {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#direito {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    float: right;
}


/* ESTILOS AUXILIARES */
#container {
    border: #000000 solid 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 90%;
}
#esquerdo {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid darkred;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#direito {
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 2px solid darkolivegreen;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="direito">direito</div>
    <div id="esquerdo">esquerdo</div>
    container
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vou dar mais uma opção usando, usando `display:grid` e como `grid-template-columns: auto 50px;` eu deixo a coluna da esquerda com largura `auto`, 100% do espaço disponível, e a coluna da direita tem valor `fixo de 50px`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código referente a imagem acima**

```css
#container {
    border: #000000 solid 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 90%;
    position: inherit;
    background-color: #eff2ff;
    display: grid;
    /* aqui eu defino que o Grid tem Duas colunas uma com width:auto e outra com 50px */
    grid-template-columns: auto 50px; 
}
#esquerdo {
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
#direito {
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="esquerdo"></div>
    <div id="direito"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui resolver isso Facilmente apenas colocando o Background-image dentro de uma Div defini o tamanho da mesma. Em seguida coloquei a propriedade no-repeat e adicionei um background-size de 100%.

```css
div {
  background-image: url(./PizzaBackground.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

div {
background-image: url(./PizzaBackground.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
width: 1920px;
height: 500px;
}