# Como fazer os elementos ajustarem automaticamente?

Tags: css, materialize

Então, tenho essa tela de botões:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Esses botões, quando clicados, redirecionam o usuário ao email, ao maps, ao telefone, enfim...

Quando o usuário NÃO tiver um desses dados, logicamente, tbm não vai ter o botão, como coloquei de exemplo a imagem acima.

O primeiro usuário tem todos os dados, o segundo não tem o link de compartilhar e o terceiro só tem telefone.

Minha dúvida é:

Como faço para que esses botões se ajustem automaticamente?

Seria bem burro da minha parte ir testando todos os dados para eu mesmo ajustar na mão, como a imagem abaixo, quando o usuário só tem telefone:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

```js
if(!email){
    if(!localizacao){
        if(!compartilhar){
           $('#' + id + '.telefone').css('width', '83.1%');

        }
     }
 }
```

Só que nao estou conseguindo pensar em outra maneira de fazer isso...

Aqui está o HTML dos botões:

```js
$(".listagem-cartoes").append(
        `<div class="item-display">
            <div class="item draggable ui-widget-content">
                <div class="side info lista-cartoneira foto" id=${id}>
                    <div class="avatar">
                        <img src="${capa}" alt="" class="circle responsive-img"> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="nomes">
                        <div class="nome-empresa lista-cartoneira"><h1>${empresa}</h1></div>        
                        <div class="nome lista-cartoneira"><h2>${nome}</h2></div>        
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side buttons">
                        <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s4 botaoCompartilhar${id}" id=${id} style="background-color: #00BFA5;">
                            <i class="material-icons compartilhar" id=${id}>open_in_new</i>
                        </div>                    
                    <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s4 botaoLocalizacao${id}" id=${id} style="background-color: #757575;">
                        <i class="material-icons localizacao" id=${id}>place</i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s4 botaoEmail${id}" id=${id} style="background-color: #ffb74d;">
                        <i class="material-icons email" id=${id}>email</i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="atalhos-cartoneira col s4 botaoTelefone" id=${id} style="background-color: #00b0ff;">
                        <i class="material-icons telefone" id=${id}>phone</i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>`
    );
```

Estou usando o Materialize 0.100.2.

Não acrescentei nada a mais no css, então acho que é desnecessário adicionar o css aqui, pois não é referente a nada nos botões.

Comment: Seria interessante você montar um [mcve]. Seu problema consiste apenas em HTML e CSS, então você consegue reproduzir sem problemas sua situação, sem depender de lógica da sua aplicação.

Comment: Aliás, no HTML dos botões sempre há os 4 elementos, então em que parte do código você verifica quais deverão estar visíveis? E por que utilizou a classe `s4` para exibir 4 elementos? Se o grid possuir 12 colunas, 4 elementos com `.s4` irão exceder a largura.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu coloquei como exemplo ali... faço uma consulta no banco e verifico os dados, qndo não tem eu removo o botão

Comment: Na minha opinião não é duplicada, o AP está procurando uma solução usando o framework mencionado na pergunta. Talvez tenha algo pronto (assim como o Bootstrap possui) sem que seja necessário aplicar css customizado para alterar os componentes.

Comment: @Renan veja que a versão do Materialize que ele está usando o Grid é baseado em floats e valores fixos (mesmo que em %) para as colunas http://archives.materializecss.com/0.100.2/grid.html. E no *helpers* do framework não exitem classes nativas para esse tipo de adaptação http://archives.materializecss.com/0.100.2/helpers.html. Então ele vai precisar de uma solução customizada de CSS, o que nos leva a marcar essa pergunta como duplicada, já que na outra pergunta tem uma opção que pode resolver o problema https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57414/97477.